# Maximizing $2\tan^{-1} x_1 + x_2$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given constants $b_1$, $b_2$ such that  $b_1 − e^{-b_2} ≥ 0$,
maximise $f(x) =2\tan^{-1} x_1 + x_2$ subject to $x_1 + x_2 ≤ b_1$, $− \ln{x_2} ≤ b_2$, $x_1 ≥ 0$, $x_2 ≥ 0$.

I am trying to learn optimisation alone and I can't figure out this problem.
I want to minimize $-f(x)$.  My Lagrangian is

$L(x,\lambda,z) = 2\tan^{-1} x_1 + x_2 - \lambda_1(z_1+x_1+x_2-b_1)-\lambda_2(-\ln{x_2}
-b_2+z_2)$

I got that $\lambda_1 \leq 0$ and I think $\lambda_2$ should be $0$ but I'm not sure. I also calculated the gradient and equaled it to $0$ but I'm not sure how to do the different cases.

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Considering that $-\ln x_2 \le b_2\equiv x_2 \ge e^{-b_2}$ for $x_2 \ge 0$

the restrictions can be transformed to

$$
g_1(x,b,\epsilon) = x_2-b_2-\epsilon^2\\
g_2(x,b,\epsilon)=b_1-b_2-\epsilon^2\\
g_3(x,b,\epsilon)=x_1+x_2-b_1+\epsilon^2\\
g_4(x,b,\epsilon)=x_1-\epsilon^2\\
g_5(x,b,\epsilon)=x_2-\epsilon^2\\
g_6(x,b,\epsilon)=b_2-\epsilon^2\\
$$

(here $b_2$ represents $e^{-b_2}$. Now with

$$
f(x) = 2\arctan x_1+x_2
$$

we have the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,b,\epsilon,\lambda) = f(x)+\sum_{k=1}^6 g(x,b,\epsilon_k)
$$

so the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \lambda_3+\lambda_4+\frac{2}{x_1^2+1}&=&0 \\
 \lambda_1+\lambda_3+\lambda_5+1&=&0 \\
 \lambda_2-\lambda_3&=&0 \\
 -\lambda_1-\lambda_2+\lambda_6&=&0 \\
 -\epsilon_1^2-b_2+x_2&=&0 \\
 -\epsilon_2^2+b_1-b_2&=&0 \\
 \epsilon_3^2-b_1+x_1+x_2&=&0 \\
 x_1-\epsilon_4^2&=&0 \\
 x_2-\epsilon_5^2&=&0 \\
 b_2-\epsilon_6^2& =& 0 \\
 -2 \epsilon_k \lambda_k & =& 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

for $k = 1,\cdots,6$